# 'Tensor' vs 'tf.Tensor' tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am exploring tensorflow internals, and sometimes when I print the value of a tensor, I will see data like the following: `Tensor("x/PlaceholderWithDefault:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)`

and other times I will see `tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)`.

What is the difference between these two expressions? Are `Tensor` and `tf.Tensor` different? And if not, why are they displayed differently (and seem to have different behavior)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the output Tensor("x/PlaceholderWithDefault:0", shape=(), dtype=int32), it is the TensorFlow placeholder object. Placeholders are symbolic tensors that act as input nodes to the TensorFlow computational graph. When you create a placeholder, you define its shape and data type but do not provide any values for it.

When you see the output "tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)", it is a TensorFlow tensor object. This output format shows the actual value of the tensor, along with its shape and data type.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks. Are all tensors with a string as the first argument placeholders?

Comment: It is not mandatory to be a placeholder. It depends on the use case. Thank You.